# Constructor of a base class is not inherited in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance

Constructors in C# are not inherited. One has to explicitly call the constructor of base class. But on the other side it is also said constructor of base class gets  automatically called before child class constructor.

Can anyone would explain this?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]. Clearly show the output you are experiencing **and the output you expect instead**.

Comment: Only parameterless constructor of base class gets called implicitly before child constructor. Because it can be done automatically. Constructor with parameter(s) must be called explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your constructor implemented, for example

```
class Human {
    public Human() {
        Console.WriteLine("I am human");
    }

    public Human(int i) {
        Console.WriteLine("I am human " + i);
    }
}

class Man : Human {
    public Man() {
        Console.WriteLine("I am man");
    }

    public Man(int i) {
        Console.WriteLine("I am man " + i);
    }
}


static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Man m1 = new Man();

    Man m2 = new Man(2);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Then the result will be:

```
I am human //this is m1
I am man   //this is m1
I am human //this is m2
I am man 2 //this is m2
```

but if you want the "m2" show as

```
I am human 2 //this is m2
I am man 2   //this is m2
```

you need to explicit call the base class's constructure

```
class Man : Human {
    public Man() {
        Console.WriteLine("I am man");
    }

    public Man(int i) : base(i) {
        Console.WriteLine("I am man " + i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't really demonstrate explicitly calling the base via `Human(int i)` though

Answer (score 0):

A class can have many constructors.  If a class is a subclass of another class, then *every* one of its constructors will call ***a*** constructor of its base class.

If you do nothing in a subclass constructor, then the base class's default (parameterless) constructor will be called implicitly before the subclass constructor's code will execute.  If you don't want this default behavior, you can pick which constructor to call.

If I take @Ivien's code and expand it a bit:

```
public class Human
{
    public Human()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am human");
    }

    public Human(int i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am human " + i);
    }
}
public class Man : Human
{
    public Man()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am man");
    }

    public Man(int i)
    {
        // The default base class constructor will be implicitly called here
        Console.WriteLine("I am man " + i);
    }
}
public class Woman : Human
{
    public Woman()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am woman");
    }
    public Woman(int i) : base(i)
    {
        // I don't want the default base class constructor, so I force a call to the other constructor
        Console.WriteLine("I am woman " + i);
    }
}
```

You will see the same thing @Ivien saw for his code, but you will see:

```
I am human 2 
I am woman 2
```

If you do something like: `var w2 = new Woman(2);`